# a newer version of iphone software is available while I am already on 12.1.2

Tags: iphone, itunes, software-update

I have iPhone 8 Plus

Around 12/15(approx) I took backup on my MacBook Pro iTunes 12.9.2.5 and then updated to 12.1.2 on phone itself by going to Settings > General > Software Update

Today I connected my iPhone 8 Plus to my same MacBook Pro and it's saying
[image: iphone8PlusUpdateMsg]

if I check on my phone Settings > General > Software Update it says your software is up to date.

Comment: it may say "your software is up to date" but does it also say 12.1.2 above that? Occasionally the check date/time can be different, so it still thinks the previous version is fine simply because it hasn't been told yet - Apple roll out in batches, so they don't get hit with 250 million downloads simultaneously.

Comment: Had the same issue yesterday. iPhone was on 12.1.2 already, iTunes insisted on updating it to 12.1.2 as well. At the end I just let it run through.

Comment: Apple [changed 12.1.2](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/12/20/apple-releases-updated-version-of-ios-12-1-2/) around 12/20.  They kept the same version number but changed the build number.  Maybe it's seeing this as an update?

Comment: I've had it ask me again if I want to update, halfway through the update process [in fact it does that a lot & has done for a loooong time; ignoring it has become a habit ;)

Comment: @fsb - interesting. I have 16C104 so I guess it's something I can't test

Comment: My About Info says 12.1.2(16C101 )

Comment: thanks for providing the newer build number helped me search the difference https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/12/20/apple-issues-second-release-of-ios-1212